# Want some simple AJAX implementation tutorial using Jquery + Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, jquery

Im new to ZF. Im struggling to implement a AJAX form submission using Jquery, can somebody point me to a good tutorial explaining the same (something which works on ZF 1.10.+)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Zend_Form to create your form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain how I have implemented Ajax submission using jQuery in Zend Framework. 
You have to build your form like the following.

```
    $form->setAttrib('id','div_form');
    $form->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
        'label' => 'Ajax Submit',
        'onclick' => "$('#div_form').load('" . "/ajax/submit" . "', $('#div_form').serializeArray() ); return false;"
    ));
```

Add the submit like the one shown above.

```
return false;
```

cancels actual submission of form.

In your AjaxController.php,

```
public function submitAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
    //Get your form data from the params
    Zend_Debug::dump($this->_getAllParams());
    //Process data using your model and return appropriate messages.
    echo "Your form is submitted";
}
```

Try the above and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Can you please explain what does this line do? form').load('" . "/ajax/submit" . "', $('#div_form').serializeArray() ); return false;"

Comment: @user648198 - whatever the output from the ajax call will be placed in the div called "div_form". you can put whatever you want there.

Comment: Thanks! so using ur example i have to add this to the form $form->setAttrib('id','div_form');  I manage to get the values in the submit action but how can I check and repopulate the form if its invalid? Do you have any example of the submit action code i can look at? Thanks so much!

Comment: if you want to repopulate the form if it is invalid, you should check each field whether it is valid using client side javascript(which can be hackable) and then submit the form via Ajax. Else use default POST submit instead of Ajax submit. Zend will repopulate the invalid form with errors displayed.